# How to load an async prop value inside a Vue "v-for" element?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Vue with Firebase Firestore.

I have a list of people displayed using a `v-for` element. The list of people is of an unknown size. Data for the list comes from Firestore which arrives asynchronously. This part is easy because I can get the data inside an `onMounted` hook or setup a Firestore listener.

But for each item in the `v-for` I want to make another `async` call to Firestore to fetch each of their images (the image urls are stored in a separate Firestore document). And I have no idea how to handle this part.

Currently, the images are all broken because `getPersonImageById(person.id)` is asynchronous. Therefore it returns `undefined` immediately, and later delivers the image url. And if I try to load the prop value using `await` like so `<img :src="await getPersonImageById(person.id)" />` I get this error:

> Error parsing JavaScript expression: 'await' is only allowed within
> async functions and at the top levels of modules. (1:1)

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```Vue
<template>
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people" :key="person.id">
    {{ person.name }}
    <img :src="getPersonImageById(person.id)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

// Simulate async database call (i.e. Firestore)
const databaseAsyncFetch = async (data) => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

// Load the people data
const people = ref();
onMounted(async () => {
  people.value = await databaseAsyncFetch([
    { id: '1', name: 'John', fruit: 'Banana' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Mary', fruit: 'Apple' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Luke', fruit: 'Orange' },
  ]);
});

// Make another async call for each "person" inside the v-for to fetch the images
const getPersonImageById = async (id) => {
  await databaseAsyncFetch(
    'https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=' + id + '.jpg'
  );
};
</script>
```

And here is a reproduction link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ljqftl?file=src/App.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't tie `:src` to a fetch. You should make a follow up fetch call after the first database fetch.  Something like:

```js
people.value = await databaseAsyncFetch([
    { id: '1', name: 'John', fruit: 'Banana' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Mary', fruit: 'Apple' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Luke', fruit: 'Orange' },
  ]);
people.value.forEach(person => { person.image = getPersonImageById(person.id) })
```

Then conditionally render the `<img>` based on whether or not person.image exists

```html
<img v-if="person?.image" :src="person.image" />
```